# Delete every other row

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a loop that deletes entire rows in a sheet to clean-up the file. So if I have row 1 to 10, I want to delete row 1, 3, 5, 7, 9.

```
Sub deleteeveryotherrow()
 For x = 1 To 10

     Rows("x:x").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        x = x + 2
        Next x

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"x:x"` is just a literal string, so will not work as you expect.

Use `Rows(x & ":" & x).Select` instead.

You should also consider running the loop backwards from 10 to 1:

`For x = 9 To 1 Step -2`

otherwise you'll get your indexing tangled up. You'll then be able to remove the line `x = x + 2`.

Comment: maybe `For x = 9 To 1 Step -2` ...?

Comment: Oops. We'll publish jointly!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub deleteeveryotherrow()

For x = 1 To 100 Step 1

 Rows(x & ":" & x).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Next x

End Sub
```

this works perfectly thanks